# Archive/release crash on start with Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-unimodules

My app starts to crash when I make an archive and send it to TestFlight. And when I open the app on a real device app waiting some time on the splash screen and then crash. But debug version works fine without any problem.

I exported the crash from my phone but I am not able to identify issue there:

```
Incident Identifier: 4D9DD2F1-E124-4AA3-BFEE-ACB83640F332
CrashReporter Key:   174a3861e99306b19bcfafa5e361aed4835d2a96
Hardware Model:      iPhone7,1
Process:             APPNAME [4880]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/AD750600-B6E2-4FAA-9A0B-2109E460BBC4/appname.app/APP
Identifier:          APPNAMEBUNDLE
Version:             6 (1.3.2)
AppStoreTools:       12D4e
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Non UI
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           APPBANDLE [1036]


Date/Time:           2021-03-22 16:17:10.4435 +0100
Launch Time:         2021-03-22 16:16:50.3099 +0100
OS Version:          iPhone OS 12.4.8 (16G201)
Baseband Version:    7.80.04
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d
Termination Description: SPRINGBOARD, scene-create watchdog 

transgression: APPBANDLE exhausted real (wall clock) time allowance of 19.92 seconds | ProcessVisibility: Foreground | ProcessState: Running | WatchdogEvent: scene-create | WatchdogVisibility: Foreground | WatchdogCPUStatistics: ( | "Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 5.260 (user 5.260, system 0.000), 13% CPU", | "Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 2.258, 6% CPU" | )
    Triggered by Thread:  0
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197d800f4 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197d7f5a0 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000198180914 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 236
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019817b824 __CFRunLoopRun + 1360
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019817afb4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
...
```

After some playing, I was able to make a release build as debug version and I had the same issue and I extract error from the Xcode console:

```
 APPNAME[4964:990367] [javascript] 'Failed to print error: ', 'Maximum call stack size exceeded.'
```

I am not able to identify what could be wrong...

**UPDATE**
The issue started when I install `react-native-unimodules` (I don't use expo just vanilla RN but I needed some lib from the expo) When I remove `unimodules` it is working fine

Comment: It looks like you have an infinite recursive loop.

Comment: hm ... but where  ... nothing happened on the splash screen and nothing happened on the first screen after there is no reason for the crash